# 32bit Reverse Engineered Encryption Function Failing 64bit

Tags: c++, security, cryptography, segmentation-fault, reverse-engineering

```
signed int _rotr( int a1, int a2 )
{
    return (a1 << a2 % 0x20u) | ((unsigned int)a1 >> (char)(32 - a2 % 0x20u));
}
int _encrypt_password( int a1, int a2, signed int a3 )
{
    signed int  v10; // [sp+10h] [bp-8h]@3
    int         result; // eax@1
    int         v4; // ebx@3
    int         v5; // edi@3
    int         v6; // esi@3
    int         v7; // eax@4
    int         v8; // [sp+14h] [bp-4h]@2
    int         v9; // [sp+Ch] [bp-Ch]@2

    result = 8 * a3 / 8;
    a3 = 8 * a3 / 8;
    if ( result > 0 )
    {
        result = a2;
        v8 = 0;
        v9 = a2;
        while ( a3 / 8 > v8 )
        {
            v4 = *(_DWORD *)v9 + *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 16);
            v6 = *(_DWORD *)(v9 + 4) + *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 20);
            v10 = 1;
            v5 = a1 + 24;
            do
            {
                v7 = *(_DWORD *)v5 + _rotr(v6 ^ v4, v6);
                v4 = v7;
                v6 = *(_DWORD *)(v5 + 4) + _rotr(v7 ^ v6, v7);
                ++v10;
                v5 += 8;
            }
            while ( v10 <= 12 );
            result = v9;
            *(_DWORD *)v9 = v4;
            *(_DWORD *)(v9 + 4) = v6;
            ++v8;
            v9 += 8;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Above is a reverse engineered set of functions which provides the encryption of a string (password) for authentication of a game client to a game server. The original encryption is no longer available and it was reverse engineered for this purpose.

The code runs perfectly in 32bit, however, when compiling for 64bit systems I run into some problems. The code builds successfully as it does in 32bit, however upon execution of the function it segfaults (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) when it hits the first v4 assignment line:

```
v4 = *(_DWORD *)v9 + *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 16);
```

I have attempted to understand the function and figure out what sort of encryption its actually providing however I've failed at that miserably. I was running with RC5 at first, but that led to about 2 days of math that ultimately proved extremely valuable to my cryptography skills but futile to the problem at hand.

I'd like to know one or both things about this code:

First and easiest, does anyone recognize the algorithm or cryptographic method that this is using? Is it even using a standard method? It looks like RC5/ROT13/DES/AES in some way shape or form to me, but I can't tell.

Second, is there any indication as to why this would fail to work in 64bit?

** Sorry, _DWORD is an unsigned long.

Comment: you are casting ints into pointers, theoretically 64 bit programs use 64bit pointers, so maybe using (void*) instead of int for storing pointers would be better

Comment: lol. Yea, I figured it isn't rot13. Honestly I don't even think it truly follows any direct encryption scheme.

_DWORD is defined as a unsigned long. (void *) in that context doesn't compile, at least not in the form it is there. I've attempted using uint64_t and a few other types, but the segfault remains.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't call something that you blindly copied from pseudocode window in IDA as "reverse engineered set of functions"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing all the occurrences of `int` and _DWORD with `int32_t` (you'll want to `#include <stdint.h>`.  You said `_DWORD` is defined as `unsigned long`, which on many 32-bit machines will be a 32-bit quantity but on 64-bit machines will often be 64.

Or if the function is actually called with addresses as its arguments, which it looks like it might be, you may want to try using `int64_t` everywhere.  Do you have an example of how the function is invoked, and some example inputs on a 64-bit system?

Comment: The function is allied with a 120byte unsigned char key and a buffered char for the password to be encrypted:

    `unsigned char buffer[] = {
        0x00, 0x5D, 0x1E, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE4, 0x55, 0xA5, 0x71, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    };`

I say buffered as this is modified with a memcpy of potentially smaller strings that leaves the trailing information there as a requirement for the authentication mechanism.

The function call is:

    `_encrypt_password( (int)rc5_cipher, (int)buffer, 16 );`

I'll try what you said and report in a moment.

Comment: Try running under `valgrind` and see what it thinks the invalid accesses are.  Also, what is `rc5_cipher`?

Comment: rc5_cipher is: `unsigned char rc5_cipher[] = {
    0xBC, 0x54, 0xE8, 0xEB, 0xF7, 0x98, 0x49, 0xB0, 0x8C, 0xA8, 0xFA, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0x54, 0xE8, 0x96,
    0x56, 0x55, 0x91, 0xA9, 0x10, 0x41, 0xE4, 0x48, 0x8F, 0x30, 0x32, 0x9F, 0x3E, 0x1D, 0xF4, 0x27...` (it goes on longer than the comment allows) total of 120 bytes.

Comment: OK, so it is actually an array, so degrades to a pointer, so your function's first argument should be of type void* or unsigned char*.  I hope you can work out from there what the rest of the types need to be and try again.  I'm guessing the 64-bit pointer to rc5_cipher is being truncated on the 64-bit system by the fact that the function is called by casting the pointer to an int, which is not really OK.

Comment: Ok, so after a few changes related to your direction I actually figured it out. There were a few things I needed to do that all kind of came together into one, though the end solution actually was the unsigned char being cast as an int. I modified _DWORD to also be uint64_t, and I changed all of the pointers to be the same as well.

Answer (score 3):

a1 and a2 are not ints, they are pointers, similarly, they are not signed, they are unsigned. On a 64 bit system these pointers may be to values higher than max(int32), you could try converting them to 64 bit sized values, say, uint64_t.

Comment: Doing so causes the same segfault... including changing every int to uint64_t entirely.